# NoReverseMatch at / on the start of the server

Tags: django, python-3.x

It's giving me an error: **NoReverseMatch at /**  targeting the base.html file (shown in the pic).But the base.html file looks fine to me.

[image]

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Medium Style editor -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Russo+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body class="loader">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar custom-navbar techfont navbar-default">
      <div class="container">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="navbar-brand bigbrand" href="{% url 'post_list' %}">My Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.github.com">GitHub</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com">LinkedIn</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li> <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" >New Post</a></li>
            <li> <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}" >Drafts</a></li>
            <li> <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" >Logout</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Welcome: {{user.username}}</a> </li>

          {% else %}
          <li> <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="nav navbar-right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> </a> </li>

          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- COntent Block -->
    <div class="content container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="blog-posts">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

  <h1 class="posttitle loader">{{post.title}}</h1>
  {% if post.published_date %}
  <div class="date postdate">
    {{post.published_date}}
  </div>

  {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">Publish</a>

  {% endif %}

  <p class="postcontent">{{post.text|safe|linebreaksbr}}</p>

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
  </a>

  <a href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </a>

  {% endif %}

<hr>
<a href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-comment">Add Comment</a>

<div class="container">
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
  <br>
  {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
  {{ comment.create_date }}
    {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
      <a href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
      </a>

      <a href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </a>
    {% endif %}

  <p>{{comment.text|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
  <p>Posted by: {{comment.author}}</p>

  {% endif %}
  {% empty %}
  <p>No comments!</p>

  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Post_list.html (The very first page that's supposed to be open on running the server)

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="centerstage">
  {% for post in post_list %}
  <div class="post">
    <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a></h1>
    <div class="date">
      <p>Published on: {{post.published_date|date:'D M Y'}}</p>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.detail %}">Comments: {{ post.approve_comments.count }}</a>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

*Blog.urls*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^drafts/$',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),
]
```

Didn't receive this error before. Came all of a sudden. Clueless as to what went wrong. How to tackle this?

Comment: please send your project structure and settings.py of your project

Comment: Did you include your blog urls in the root `urls.py`?

Comment: Yes I've included blog urls in the root urls.py

Comment: @vorujack in settings.py, I've just added the path to template directory, also just included STATIC_ROOT and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## the problem is in post_list.html or post_detail.html .

basically you are having the url that is not matches with any urls in urls.py

`ie({% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %})`

so check your post_list.html and post_detail.html your base.html is well and good

The same error i was facing i looked to my firstly rendered page and the extra url was there.

Comment: Yup got it. Problem is in post_list.html in the last anchor tag. it should be pk=post.pk rather than pk=post.detail. Thanks.

Comment: Ticked. won't reflect you. But it's noted by the site.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message, the blog url with arguments `{'pk: ''}` is not found. This basically means that on the page where you're doing `"{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}"`, `post` is probably `None` or not an object you're expecting. You need to check that your `{% for post in post_list %}` actually returns posts.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is in post_list.html in the last anchor tag. it should be pk=post.pk rather than pk=post.detail. Thanks.